# How would oral medication be given to patient in ICU that can't swallow?

Tags: swallow-swallowing, drug-administration, icu-intensive-care-unit

How would oral medication be given to patient in ICU that can't swallow? I was told that the tablets are grind and put in water then provided through a tube. Is this true? How would the nurse know the effect of interaction resulting from mixing those ground pills? Thanks.

Comment: You can always answer your own question instead of editing it to include an answer. This way, the community will know whether you are still looking for an answer or not.

Comment: For such a patient In an ICU virtually all drugs would be given IV.

Comment: @CareyGregory, but some are still administrated via tube, please see the link on my "answer".

Answer (score 1):

Through a nasogastric tube.
What you call "interaction" would be previously known by general and common knowledge of pharmacology.
The doctor must know about those interactions, the nurse simply administrates what was indicated

Comment: Welcome to Health.SE. Since health is an important topic, the site has a strict policy that **all answers** should be [backed up with reliable references](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) in order to provide the community with the means to assess the merit of the answer, regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://health.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112/what-are-reliable-sources)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help].

Answer (score 1):

After some research I found this topic which answers part of my question. It does not answer the chemical effects of mixing drugs outside the human body.

1-[Nasogastric medications](http://www.atitesting.com/ati_next_gen/skillsmodules/content/Medication-Administration-2/equipment/nasogastric.html).

2-[drug-administration-via-a-nasogastric-tube](https://www.nursingtimes.net/clinical-archive/gastroenterology/drug-administration-via-a-nasogastric-tube/200984.article). (may require subscription!)

I find the process of grinding different pills and serving them altogether strange I am almost sure that this can't be generally correct.

Comment: Reading the link you provided requires a subscription.

Comment: Sorry about that, I can open the page without subscription! Maybe it is free for 3rd world countries! I have included the path in plain text, in case this works.

Comment: It's the exact same link, and the link isn't the problem. The problem is we can't read it. In general, answers that are nothing more than a link are considered undesirable because links have a habit of going bad over time. Your complete answer needs to be in text here, not in a link to somewhere we can't get to now or 5 years from now. (You have enough rep elsewhere to know all this.)

Comment: @CareyGregory, I see, I have added a link to another page, hoping this can be reached freely. Your point of providing text is very valid, however, I have zero medical experience and I am unable to provide scientific answer, I am the one who asked the question, so I could not elaborate more about the answer. When I added an Edit to the question, I was advised to create an answer. Your point is still valid though.